# I'm trying to access an instance of an img when a div is clicked

Tags: jquery

i have an click event that makes the images grow to 100% of the div but i only want the image from div being clicked to do this. the code below doesn't work and if i drop the instance off it changes all the images, which doesn't work

$(this).$('img).addClass('big');

Comment: Google a bit, explore the jQuerry documentation, open browser console to read your errors. `$(this).$('img)` you have in 15 characters many wrong things. Notice the `'` all alone... also or use `$(this)` or `$('img')` just not like you did. If you need a `"img"` being **child** of `this` than use `.find()`. See the documentation.

Comment: thanks, .find() was exactly what i was looking for. i was only trying to ask it you could find an instance of an image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your image is a child of the clicked DIV than use:

```
$(this).find("img").addClass('big');
```

Here's an example

```js
var $allImg = $(".box").find("img");      // Collect all images


$(".box").on("click", function() {

  var $img = $(this).find("img");         // get this image
  
  $allImg.not( $img ).removeClass("big"); // Remove from $allImg (not $img)
  $img.toggleClass("big");                // Toggle from $img 
});
```

```css
.box{
  display: inline-block;
  border: 4px solid #000;
}
.box img{
  vertical-align: top;
  transition: 1s;
}

.big{
  transform: scale(1.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"><img src="//placehold.it/50x50/0bf" alt="My Image 1"></div>
<div class="box"><img src="//placehold.it/50x50/f0b" alt="My Image 2"></div>
<div class="box"><img src="//placehold.it/50x50/0fb" alt="My Image 3"></div>
<div class="box"><img src="//placehold.it/50x50/fb0" alt="My Image 4"></div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: this worked great, i would vote it up but my question got down voted putting my reputation under 15 but thanks

Comment: idk how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starters, you're missing a closing single quote in ('img)

As for what else might be wrong, I have no idea since that's all the code you posted.